# Navigation View in Tab View Child Views SwiftUi

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I have started learning swiftUI so I have question about Navigation View. My app starts with splash screen which is embedded in Navigation View and after that I have navigation link to the second screen which is Tab View. Do I need navigation views in child views of Tab View if I have some button etc and I also need to go to other screens from them or I use primary navigation view which tab view is embedded in?

Comment: A `TabView` should not be inside a `NavigationView` but each `tabItem` can have a `NavigationView`

Answer (score 0):

When using both TabView and NavigationView, TabView should always be the parent view and should contain NavigationView inside it.
Hope this clarifies what you’re looking for?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).